# Combination of all possible numbers following digit rules in python

Tags: python, generator, combinations, python-itertools

Looking for a "pythonish" and simple way to achieve the generation of all possible numbers following different ranges of digits.

**Example:** Generate strings (representing number) with digits '01234567' ranging from [0-4] occurrences and '8' ranging from [0-10] occurrences and '9' from [0-100]
Example of numbers generated: *{'11337899999999', '33567899999999', '245678999999999999999',...}*
*(all generated numbers should be with sequential digits... so '88119' isn't valid)*

So far I came up with a very simple and clean code but that doesn't do exactly what I need:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
length = 50
for x in combinations_with_replacement('0123456789', length):
   print("".join(x), end=', ')
```

This will generate the numbers I need but as well a bunch of unnecessary ones, which will delay significantly the execution.

Thought on generating the digits one by one according to the rules and concatenating... but believe this will be a "dirty" solution and as well inefficient.
Anyone knows a nice clean way of doing this? *(Itertools, or any other library is welcome)*

Comment: Are you sure you need to actually create all of the roughly 65536000 combinations? That seems like a lot of numbers, ranging somewhere in GB of memory. What do you intend to create these for?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How did you get that number? I get 433,984,375 (= `5**8 * 11 * 101`).

Comment: @KellyBundy Lower-bound estimate as `4 ** 8 * 10 * 100`. That's the curse of using half-open intervals all day...

Comment: This is intended to solve a Project Euler problem, where I want to generate long strings of digits... some up to thousands of length. however... I found out roughly the logic behind these strings... example: lower digits (up to 7 have a maximum of 4 occurences) 8 digits have up to 10 occurences, and 9 digits at the end... complete the rest of the string

Comment: @JoaodeOliveira And what does the problem require you to *do* with all that data? I doubt they want all those GB of numbers.

Comment: I can of course.. this was to avoid "sharing" my line of thought while solving the problem, not sure it breaks Project Euler's idea of not sharing the solution. The problem in question is 254... in order to generate all possible g(x) numbers instead of bruteforce.. believe we need to generate permutations of digits, which goes way faster... and it's getting me into the 60's solution... nevertheless I can see it's still not perfect.

Comment: https://projecteuler.info/problem=254

Comment: The PE descriptions looks very much like you should not (and practically cannot) try all combinations. Note how f(342) = f(432) = f(234) since f does not respect the ordering of digits. So any permutation of the same digits has the same result for f. You should generate *the single smallest* permutation, not *all* permutations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully undersand you problem, but i think i have a solution :

```
import random

def generate(string = ""):

    for i in range(9):
        i += 1
        if i <= 7:
            occurrence = 4
        elif i == 8:
            occurrence = 10
        else:
            occurrence = 100

        string = string + str(i)* random.randint(0, occurrence)
    return string

a = generate()
print(a)
```

if you want it to be lenght 50 use:

```
a = a[:50]
```

Comment: Thanks @Fredericka for the suggestion. The only downside with your solution is that it's based on random generation. So 1) it looks to me a bit slow, 2) and more important ... it doesn't ensure that we go through all the numbers... it "might" hit the number, but it might not.

Comment: Do you want to genereate all possible configuration? I am not sure i completely understant your ploblem.

Comment: As I pointed to previous comments, this is to help me solve a ProjectEuler exercise (254), where I need to find numbers that match certain criterias... in order to generate such numbers, the fastest way is to generate numbers given a condition of factors. example of numbers: 1333579999999999999999999 12245556666799999999999 123345556666799999999999, 12245578899999999... as you see there is a pattern here

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up picking the itertools.combinations_with_replacement and alter it to accept an array containing maximum usage of digits...
Pretty simple, but it's working.
If anyone has any hints on how to look at it differently or adapt anything to speed up, I will be happy with it.

```
def combinations_with_replacement2(iterable, m_digits, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r: return
    count = [0] * n
    indices = [0] * r
    d = 0
    for i in range(r):
        if count[d] == m_digits[d]: d += 1

    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1: break
        else: return

        count = [0] * n
        d = indices[i] + 1
        for f in range(i, r):
            indices[f] = d
            count[d] += 1
            if count[d] == m_digits[d]: d += 1

        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```